# If $A,B$ is nilpotent then $G$ is solvable?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

let $G$ be a finite group and let $A,B$ be two proper nilpotent subgroup. If

$$AB=G$$ then is it true that $G$ is necessarily solvable ?

Comment: Can I learn the reason of downvote ?

Comment: I was not the downvoter, but questions like this are regularly closed because they lack context. That is, you have asked a question without including any information about the source of the problem, why you think it might be true or false, etc. I don't have any particular opinions  about whether or not questions should be closed for that reason (it might be to avoid people just getting some else to do their homework for them).

Comment: It is a longstanding open problem as to whether this result holds for infinite groups. I think it has been proved under various additional hypotheses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Wielandt-Kegel theorem states that all finite dinilpotent groups $G=AB$ are solvable. So it is true.

Reference: [This article](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.hokmj/1351257811) by Carocca and Matos, with references to Kegel and Wieland.

Comment: thank you, I knew this theorem in that format; when $A,B$ are hall subgroups. But , In your reference there is no such assumption.

Comment: No, you do not need more than nilpotent subgroups.